# segmentation fault in assembly printf

Tags: assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, att

I am trying to write an assembly function that copies a part of one string to another in assembly (for a class assignment). Part of it is checking if the indices between which to copy are legal (within the bounds of the strings) and if not, print a short error message and exit without changing anything. The function works fine for non-error inputs, but when I specifically enter erroneous arguments (such as copying indices 10-20 in strings of length 15), it segfaults somewhere inside printf.

I am using AT&T X86 assembly.

What could be causing this?

code:

```
pstrijcpy:
    pushl   %ebp            #save old FP
    movl    %esp, %ebp      #set new FP
#using eax, ebx, ech, edx, 
    pushl   %ebx            #back %ebx up.

    movl    16(%ebp), %eax      #the dword with i
    movb    %al, %bl        #store i in %bl
    movl    20(%ebp), %eax      #the dword with j
    movb    %al, %bh        #store j in %bh
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax       #initialize eax to dst ptr.
    movb    (%eax), %dh     #%dh <- dst.len
    addl    $1, %eax        #advance %eax by one byte to the string
    movl    12(%ebp), %ecx      #initialize ecx to src ptr.
    mov (%ecx), %dl     #%dl <- src.len
    addl    $1, %ecx        #advance %ecx by one byte to the string

    cmpb    %dl, %bl        #i-src.len
    jg  cpyERROR        #if >: goto error
    cmp %dl, %bh        #j-src.len
    jg  cpyERROR        #if >: goto error
    cmpb    %dh, %bl        #i-dst.len
    jg  cpyERROR        #if >: goto error
    cmp %dh, %bh        #j-dst.len
    jg  cpyERROR        #if >: goto error

    #now I will add i to the pointers that point to the strings.
    push    %edx            #back edx up
    movzbl  %bl, %edx       #apparently I can use 'movl %bl, %eax', so I did this.
    addl    %edx, %eax      #advance dst to ith character
    addl    %edx, %ecx      #advance src to ith character
    popl    %edx            #restore edx

    cpyTEST:
    cmpb    %bh, %bl        #compare i with j
    jg  cpyDONE         #once i is greater than j, we are done.

    cpyLOOP:
    movb    (%ecx), %dl     #Since I already checked that i and j <= the lengths, I can use them
    movb    %dl, (%eax)     #Move byte from src to dst.
    addl    $1, %ecx        #Increment src to next byte
    addl    $1, %eax        #Increment dst to next byte
    addl    $1, %ebx        #Increment i by 1.
    jmp cpyTEST         #goto test

    cpyERROR:
    pushl   error           #push the message to be printed.
    call    printf          #use printf to print error message

    cpyDONE:
    popl    %ebx            #restore %ebx
    movl    8(%ebp), %eax       #set return value to be dst pointer.
    movl    %ebp, %esp      #restore the old stack pointer - release all used memory.
    popl    %ebp            #restore old frame pointer (the caller function frame)
    ret             #return to caller function (main)

    .section .rodata
error:      .string "invalid input!\n"  # error message.
```

Comment: You want `pushl $error`. You missed the `$`.

Comment: Mmmmmmm. The derps are real. Thanks man.

Comment: Eventually, you might come to realise that you are not the yardstick by which everything else is judged.

Comment: @Weather Vane Ummm, what?